# Program time vs Music time

Tags: c#, performance, time, microsoft-metro

I've been trying to make a game with music in it. I've been using a timer to keep track of the program's running time but I haven't been able to match up the music's playing time with my program's running time. Even when I get rid of almost all of my code it's still slower. Here's what I have for code.

```
    int timeInterval;
    int runningTime;
    DispatcherTimer drawTimer;
    public Game()
    {
        timeInterval = 100;
        drawTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        drawTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(timeInterval);
        drawTimer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;

    }
    protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        runningTime = 0;

        StorageFile file;
        StorageFolder InstallationFolder = Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation;
        string filePath = @"soundtrack.m4a";
        musicPlayer = new MediaElement();
        file = await InstallationFolder.GetFileAsync(filePath);
        var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
        musicPlayer.SetSource(stream, file.ContentType);
        musicPlayer.Play();
        drawTimer.Start();
    }

    void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, object e)
    {
        runningTime += timeInterval;

        if ((runningTime / 1000) % 10 == 0)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Music: " + musicPlayer.Position.Seconds + "Running time: " + (runningTime / 1000) % 60);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Edit: Here's some of the output

```
    Music: 0Running time: 0
    Music: 0Running time: 0
    Music: 0Running time: 0
    Music: 0Running time: 0
    Music: 0Running time: 0
    Music: 0Running time: 0
    Music: 0Running time: 0
    Music: 0Running time: 0
    Music: 0Running time: 0
    Music: 11Running time: 10
    Music: 11Running time: 10
    Music: 11Running time: 10
    Music: 11Running time: 10
    Music: 12Running time: 10
    Music: 12Running time: 10
    ...
    Music: 9Running time: 0
    Music: 10Running time: 0
    Music: 10Running time: 0
    Music: 10Running time: 0
    Music: 10Running time: 0
    Music: 10Running time: 0
    Music: 10Running time: 0
    Music: 10Running time: 0
    Music: 10Running time: 0
    Music: 10Running time: 0
```

Comment: why the mod 60? Wouldn't runningtime(milliseconds) / 1000 get you the running time in seconds?

Comment: The musicPlayer gives me just the seconds part of it's position. So at 1:26 it will give me 26. I did mod 60 on the running time so it would match up.

Comment: oh ok, that makes sense. My guess, then, is that `musicPlayer.Play()` probably has some initialization/buffering/loading, etc., that it needs to do before it starts actually playing. How far is it behind?

Comment: It depends on the timeInterval. With the interval at 50, when runningTime got back to 0 it was 20 seconds behind. With the interval at 100 it was 10 seconds behind at that point.

Comment: Use StopWatch to time it rather than Timer - it is more accurate (Timer - both types - has an accuracy and precision of 15ms at best). Also, why not use the music position as your draw timer time (take snapshots of player position at each timer interval and calc the time that has passed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DispatcherTimer.Interval` is the minimum amount of time that will pass between Tick events. Usually it is more. You should use something like `_startTime = DateTime.Now` at the beginning and later do `_runningTime = DateTime.Now - _startTime`. You might also want to wait for `musicPlayer.CurrentStateChanged` until `musicPlayer.CurrentState == MediaElementState.Playing` before measuring the `_startTime`.

Then again - why not just get `musicPlayer.Position` as your `_runningTime` value?